# Javascript scrollTo only fires on complete page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've given up on this, seemingly done everything and followed practically every link on the internet looking for a fix, to no avail.

I'm using the jquery `scrollTo()` and `localScroll()` plugin to animate some scrolling on several pages of my site to anchors/ id's. The problem is, it only scrolls with animation when the page is either completely reloaded in the browser, or visited directly via its URL (the same as a complete reload). If you follow a link to a page using navigation, `scrollTo()`, the plugin does not work and instead it's a jump to anchors (default behaviour).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.home .col-xs-6').localScroll();
    $('.tour .btn-group').localScroll();
});
```

The javascript is loaded in a file which does appear in the HEAD (I've checked), and I've also tried putting the above code directly on the page where the .btn-group links are, but it still only works every time on a complete browser refresh, and like I said, when you navigate to a page which contains the above code using site navigation, it reverts to default behaviour.

I've also tried changing the `ready` function to `on('load')` which did nothing, and I've included `preventDefault();` which also did nothing to help.

This seems so simple yet I can't get it to work properly!

Comment: This problem is when you have hash in your url, like `yourwebsite.com/coolpage#thispart`?  Or is it even when you use a normal url like `yourwebsite.com/othercoolpage`

Comment: @RustyToms the problem occurs even when the url is at root level, with or without the #hash attached at the end. I think it actually has something to do with turbolinks in rails, I'm looking in to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing away with the plugins compeletely and went with this solution below:

```
$(document).on('page:load', function() {
$(".scroll").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         //calculate destination place
         var dest=0;
         if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
              dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
         }else{
              dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
         }
         //go to destination
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1500,'swing');
     });
});
```

which works. I just need to add `scroll` to the link class. I believe part of the problem had to do with the turbolinks gem in rails, so I added the `page:load` function which got it to work. Unfortunately even with the added function, `localScroll()` still had issues, but the this seems to work just as well.